# How to find the Interface card attached with server running asterisk?

Tags: centos, asterisk, command-line-interface

I want to find out the interface card being used for asterisk and how many channels are supported by that card.

Comment: It might be worth to study how this `gem` is doing it or use the gem directly: https://github.com/emilianodellacasa/ruby-asterisk

Comment: Do you want to know how many ports or modules got the card or what type of card are you using, ie. FXO/S, GSM, ISDN, PRI ? `lspci -vvvv` shows the detected PCI cards and `dahdi_cfg -vvvvv` the dahdi "Digium Asterisk Hardware Device Interface" configuration. The number of SIP or IAX2 Channels are limited by bandwidth and CPU or by a limit of a configuration, ie. `call-limit` at sip.conf or ISDN channels at [dahdi.conf](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/DAHDI).

Comment: It's not possible to run lspci utility directly due to using a tunnel from one server to another server for safe logging, so lspci utility doesn't work here. Any other way to find out information?

Answer (score 0):

There are few sources to find card installed

1) Open computer, push out card and find what writen on card. This is most accurate method

2) use lspci utility. Sometimes it can help

3) install dahdi, do dahdi_genconf and check what it say.

4) check dmesg or /var/log/messages.

5) check /dev/dahdi/* and /proc/dahdi/*

6) hire expert who can interpret all result and say if posible say what card you have.